# Automated symbolic commutator tool

Tags: resource-recommendations, computational-physics, commutator, software

Is there a software tool (perhaps  Mathematica extension?) designed to help with doing algebraic manipulations of non-commutative objects? Specifically, what I'm after is an interface along the lines of

```
set [A,B] = C
set [A,D] = A
set [A,C] = 0
move_right(ABCD, A)
==> BCDA + BCA + C^2 D
```

I've implemented something like this in Python, but before sinking any more time into it I wanted to check I wasn't reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Writing something like this in *Mathematica* isn't that hard to do, once you know it will enough.  It's a matter of writing replacement rules that you can apply recursively (using `//.` or `ReplaceRepeated`) to expand out the commutators and move a particular operator to the right.  There are also third-part packages written like `NCAlgebra`, although I don't know if that has this specific operation.

Comment: Might [math.se] or [mathematica.se] (if not [softwarerecs.se]) be better suited for this math question?